# More efficient to have one query loadng a lot of data, or multiple queries loading smaller chunks?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm planning on building a page with multiple "tabs" (up to 4) within it, and up to 25 "rows" per tab. Would it be more efficient to load all (up to) 4 tabs worth of data at once, or would it be better to load the first tabs data, then if the second is clicked to ajax in that set? Or would it really just depend on the query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the query.

Google paginates search results because a single query might bring back millions of hits, ranked by likelihood of usefulness.

If the queries are small, the answer doesn't matter much.  The only thing users might notice is network latency.

Comment: If it helps any, the queries will be on ~4 tables with ~10 fields total loaded. The queries themselves will be rather simple, and like I said I'd be returning a maximum of 100 rows. With this in mind, it wouldn't really matter which way I went about it?

Comment: I don't think so, unless one or more of those columns are CLOBs or BLOBs.  Then you have to worru about size.  You should be able to calculate how much memory each one takes up and decide for yourself.  Serializing them as JSON objects will make it easy for your AJAX call and the browser.